# expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type 'uint?' (aka 'Optional<UInt32>')

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am getting below error during Objective-C to Swift code change. Thanks

```
class func shareLevelUp(toFacebook level: uint, from vc: UIViewController?) {
        let report = GymStatusReport.statusReportForLevel(level)
        switch report.level {
        case 1:
            // something
        case 2:
            // something
        case 3:
            // something
        case 4:
            // something
        default:
            return
        }
}
```

expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type 'uint?' (aka 'Optional')

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Problem is, we don't know how `GymStatusReport.statusReportForLevel` is declared, or what its `level` is declared as.

Comment: level declared as uint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like `report.level` is an optional value. You need to unwrap it or you need your switch to have optional patterns.

Unwrapping it would look like this:

```
class func shareLevelUp(toFacebook level: uint, from vc: UIViewController?) {
    let report = GymStatusReport.statusReportForLevel(level)
    guard let level = report.level else {
        return
    }
    switch level {
    case 1:
        // something
    case 2:
        // something
    case 3:
        // something
    case 4:
        // something
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Matching optionals would look like this:

```
class func shareLevelUp(toFacebook level: uint, from vc: UIViewController?) {
    let report = GymStatusReport.statusReportForLevel(level)
    switch report.level {
    case .some(1):
        // something
    case .some(2):
        // something
    case .some(3):
        // something
    case .some(4):
        // something
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Matching an `UInt32?` against integer literals *does* compile in my Xcode 9.3.1.

Comment: it compiles with me even parameter is uint?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `toFacebook level: uint` to an int when using it:

```
class func shareLevelUp(toFacebook level: uint, from vc: UIViewController?) {
    let report = GymStatusReport.statusReportForLevel(level)
    switch Int(report.level) {
    case 1:
        // something
    case 2:
        // something
    case 3:
        // something
    case 4:
        // something
    default:
        return
    }
```

}